# Why do my bots in pygame move at such an inconsistent speed?

Tags: python, pygame, frame-rate

So my problem is that my bot will move at an inconsistant speed and sometimes not even move. I've tried changing fps with `clock.ticks(30)` (And less then that) but it just won't go any smoother!

```
pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

bot4x = random.randint(0, 600)
bot4y = random.randint(0, 600)

randb4 = round(random.randint(0, 4))

def bot4():
    screen.blit(pygame.image.load("DOT.png"), (bot4x, bot4y))

clock.tick(60)
run = True
while run:
    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

        if randb4 == 1:
            bot4x = bot4x + 5
        elif randb4 == 2:
            bot4x = bot4x - 5
        elif randb4 == 3:
            bot4y = bot4y + 5
        elif randb4 == 4:
            bot4y = bot4y - 5

        if bot4x >= 568:
            bot4x = 568
        elif bot4x <= 0:
            bot4x = 0
        elif bot4y >= 568:
            bot4y = 568
        elif bot4y <= 0:
            bot4y = 0
    bot4()
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a matter of [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html). You have to compute the movement in the application loop instead of the event loop:

```py
pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

bot4x = random.randint(0, 600)
bot4y = random.randint(0, 600)

randb4 = round(random.randint(0, 4))

def bot4():
    screen.blit(pygame.image.load("DOT.png"), (bot4x, bot4y))

clock.tick(60)
run = True
while run:
    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    # INDENTATION
    #<--|

    if randb4 == 1:
        bot4x = bot4x + 5
    elif randb4 == 2:
        bot4x = bot4x - 5
    elif randb4 == 3:
        bot4y = bot4y + 5
    elif randb4 == 4:
        bot4y = bot4y - 5

    if bot4x >= 568:
        bot4x = 568
    elif bot4x <= 0:
        bot4x = 0
    elif bot4y >= 568:
        bot4y = 568
    elif bot4y <= 0:
        bot4y = 0

    bot4()
    pygame.display.update()
```